# How to set a initial zoom level for a map?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion.
In this app I got a mapview. I can display this fine but I want to set an initial zoom level to the annotation area instead of a fully zoomed out view. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
map = MKMapView.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRectMake(10, 10, (hash[:width]-20), (hash[:height]-20)))
    map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard
    map.delegate = self
    map.showsUserLocation = true
    map.setCenterCoordinate(location, animated:true)
    map.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `longitudeDelta` and `latitudeDelta` fields of the `MKCoordinateSpan` structure:

```
MKCoordinateSpan span; span.latitudeDelta = .001;
span.longitudeDelta = .001;
//the .001 here represents the actual height and width delta
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center = newLocation.coordinate; region.span = span;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
```

Of course you can store the span for example as default zoom level.

Here's what docs say:

"**The region displayed by the map is defined by the region property, which is a structure of type MKCoordinateRegion. The MKCoordinateRegion structure contains a member called center (of type CLLocationCoordinate2D) and another member called span (of type MKCoordinateSpan).
The MKCoordinateSpan structure in turn contains two members: latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta (both of type CLLocationDegrees, which is a double)
Both members define the amount of distance to display for the map*:

➤ *latitudeDelta — One degree of latitude is approximately 111 kilometers (69 miles)*.

➤ *longitudeDelta — One degree of longitude spans a distance of approximately 111 kilometers (69 miles) at the equator but shrinks to 0 kilometers at the poles.
Examine the value of these two structures as you zoom in and out of the map — they are a representation of the map’s zoom level.*"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to zoom with respect to the location of the user, try this:

```
MKUserLocation *userLocation = map.userLocation;
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (userLocation.location.coordinate, 50, 50);
[map setRegion:region animated:NO];
```